# mysql display date instead of long for select results

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to display a date instead of a long on the result of `select * from table_name`. All answers on SO refer to converting the date on the `where` clause. But I dont want to filter using in date format, I want to **display results** in date format, and not long.

Edit

```
--------------------------+----------------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| connectionUniqueIdentity | deviceUniqueIdentity | simCard1 | simCard2 | phoneNumber1 | phoneNumber2 | lastUpdatedDate | rowStatus | activationDate |
+--------------------------+----------------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| -1166116395              | 823167013            | simCard1 | simCard2 | phoneNumber1 | phoneNumber2 |   1413371737879 |         0 |  1413371737879 |
| -1301899739              | 823167013            | simCard1 | simCard2 | phoneNumber1 | phoneNumber2 |   1413371395494 |         1 |  1413371395494 |
```

I need it to be like

```
--------------------------+----------------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| connectionUniqueIdentity | deviceUniqueIdentity | simCard1 | simCard2 | phoneNumber1 | phoneNumber2 | lastUpdatedDate | rowStatus | activationDate |
+--------------------------+----------------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| -1166116395              | 823167013            | simCard1 | simCard2 | phoneNumber1 | phoneNumber2 |   2nd Oct 2014 |         0 |  15th Oct 2014 |
| -1301899739              | 823167013            | simCard1 | simCard2 | phoneNumber1 | phoneNumber2 |   3rd Oct 2014 |         1 |  18th Oct 2014 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(1413439433));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourDate), '%y-%m-%d %h:%i%p') AS FormattedDate
FROM TableName
```

- [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) functions:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_value), '%d/%m/%y %h:%i%p') 
FROM table_name
```